# SQL Server : function to change the date format yyyymmddThhmmssZ

Tags: sql, sql-server

Created a function to change the date to this format `yyyymmddThhmmssZ`

Here is the function

```
    USE [IMT]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetForamttedDate]    Script Date: 09/05/2014 12:46:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      rthomas
-- Create date: 04/08/14
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetForamttedDate]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @InitialDate smalldatetime
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
Declare  @FormatDateInitial varchar(50) 
Declare  @FormatDate varchar(50)
Declare  @FormatDateFinal VARCHAR(50)
Declare @Debug      BIT = 0

SET @FormatDateInitial =  (SELECT convert(varchar(30), @InitialDate,121))
SET @FormatDate =(SELECT SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,1,4)+SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,6,2)+SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,9,2)+' '+SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,12,2)+SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,15,2)+SUBSTRING(@FormatDateInitial,18,2))
SET @FormatDateFinal= STUFF(@FormatDate,9,1,'T')+'Z'
return @FormatDateFinal

END

GO
```

And it is returning `20140805T121109Z`

But when I use this function for a date column in the table it returns only one character.

```
select function_name(date_column) from table
```

returns only 2

Please help me

Comment: Please provide the function's definition including the parameters, the type and content of the column. Also, using varchar(max) is pointless - you aren't expecting a 2 GB blob at any point

Comment: Why are you handling presentation in the database? This really should be the job of the presentation layer.

Comment: I almost bet you have a `RETURNS VARCHAR` without any **length** for the varchar defined - then you get a default length of **1 character**. If so, please read (and **embrace!**) [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: It is because date_column doesn't have **Time zone offset**.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Then it wouldn't work in the original sample either. `smalldatetime` doesn't have an offset. Anyway, the code doesn't try to access or retrieve any offset anywhere

Comment: @marc_s Another bad habit to kick: Using `varchar(max)`

Comment: @rinuthomaz Please post the entire function, including the parameters and return type

Comment: @marc_s , Thanks you for pointing out... I have corrected it. changed RETURN VARCHAR to RETURN VARCHAR(50)

Comment: why would you return VARCHAR(50) when you know you only need 16? Why would you ask us to troubleshoot a function without posting the function?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You are absolutely right, but i thought "date_column" have **date** datatype.

Comment: I think it's time to delete this question. Putting the fixed function in the question will simply confuse whoever encounters it next

Comment: Do you want me to delete this ? I have not added the fix in the question.. Question still have RETURN VARCHAR instead of RETURN VARCHAR(16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetForamttedDate] (@InitialDate smalldatetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR
```

This `RETURNS VARCHAR` will give you a default length of **1 character** !

You should get in the habit of **always** explicitly defining a valid length for any `VARCHAR` parameter and variable whenever you use one!

Please see (and embrace!) this blog post on that topic

- [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)